# How can I change the size of a WebRTC video stream?

Tags: css, webrtc

I inherited a website that I'd like to improve. One feature of the site is that two people can see each other over webcam. The website uses a WebRTC video stream for this. However, it doesn't look very good at the moment. The stream is inside a div container with the ID "video-grid". This container in turn is inside a column. Right now, the videostream overlaps this column:

[image: Text]

I tried using CSS like this:

```
#video-grid video {
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

But that doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `max-width` to 100% like so

```
#video-grid video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```